# Android: make text and drawable inside EditText to have padding

Tags: android, android-edittext

There is EditText pictured on the left.
How to make text inside EditText and drawableRight to have padding as on the right?

[image]

The EditText has rounded corners, see `android:background`,
however there is no interval set from EditText left edge to text start and from drawableRight to the EditText right edge.

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/search_editbox"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/search_execute_imageview"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/layout_back_logo"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext_states"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/abc_ic_clear_holo_light"
    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
    android:hint="@string/search_hint"
    android:maxLength="20"
    android:padding="5dip"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
    android:textSize="@dimen/main_text_size" />
```

I tried

```
    android:paddingLeft="30dp"
    android:paddingRight="30dp"
```

but it had no result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, it will work-

`android:drawablePadding="30dp"` for interval between drawable and text.

Edit: actually remove `padding` and `paddingLeft` and `paddingRight`

Comment: This did not work for me. That sets interval between text and drawableRight, but not from drawableRight to right edge.
Also what about left side of the EditText where there is no drawable, but rounded coners.

Comment: Have given 'paddingLeft' attribute after removing the 'padding'attribute?

Comment: That was it: should not use `padding` and `paddingLeft` in the same time.